# Calculate business days between 2 pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, python-datetime

I have 2 pandas series with the same indexes and different date values, both looking like this:

```
code     section
  Y        ABC      2023-03-25
           BCD      2023-03-25
           DEF      2023-03-25
                       ...    
  Z        BCD     2023-02-24
           EFG     2023-02-02
```

How do I calculate the total business days between them? Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
(LastDates - FirstDates).dt.days + 1
```

But I know I'm getting the total days between the 2 series. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [busday_count](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html) from numpy

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

start_dates = pd.Series([dt.date(2023,1,1), dt.date(2023,1,1)])
last_dates = pd.Series([dt.date(2023,2,1), dt.date(2023,2,5)])

# returns np.array
print(np.busday_count(start_dates.tolist(), last_dates.tolist()))
```

```
[22 25]
```